# What is the Timeline "closure" event?

Tags: support, timeline

Upon looking at the Timeline CSS, I noticed an interesting class:

```
.post-timeline-v2 .post-timeline .event-type>span.closure {
    background-color: #9D81B3;
    color: #fafafb
}
```

I've never seen the Closure reason actually used, especially for, well, the seemingly obvious question closure. Instead, this is listed under the `history` event:

> [image: timeline history event]

It's also not used for close votes, so what possible purpose does it have? Will it have a purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used to style close (and reopen) votes in the *moderator* version of the timeline.

[image]